# Xcode Broken UIView

Tags: ios, swift, ios13

it seems like I updated Xcode and suddenly my app's UI broke.

The UIViewController is embedded in a Navigation bar, and the parent viewcontroller is visible behind it.
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your app isn't broken. This is how iOS 13 displays presented view controllers. There's nothing to fix.

Answer (score -1):

You're presenting this ViewController modally. By default `UIViewController.modalPresentationStyle` is `.automatic`, and it's `.pageSheet` in most cases on iOS 13.
You should specify modal presentation style, when presenting that ViewController. It's should look like

```
let vc = SomeVC()
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .overFullScreen
present(vc, animated: true)
```

In storyboard, you should tap on Segue and change it's `Presentation`

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MpGn.png)

For details, you can visit that [medium blog](https://medium.com/@hacknicity/view-controller-presentation-changes-in-ios-13-ac8c901ebc4e).

Comment: Super helpful answer, thank you!

Weirdly, the gradient no longer covers the search bar. Is this a related issue?

Comment: @markocalvocruz it depends on how gradient bar is implemented, need more details

Comment: GradientView Constraints: Top = (Superview.top - 200) || Bottom = (TableView.top)

Comment: The TableView Controller still appears in the Storyboard like a Page Sheet even though i followed the suggestions you mentioned. I'll post a pic

Comment: It looks like the navigation bar's backgroundImage does not extend to the search controller